# Sonomo 14.0 SwiftUI Camera Activation Problem

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to get live camera feed on a window on Mac screen with following code.
But I am getting warnings ;

AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600001204460> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

CMIO_DAL_PlugInManagement.cpp:913:CreatePlugIn Could not find plugin with kCMIOHardwarePlugInTypeID

and camera LED shines green for a few seconds and no feed.

I could not find the reason.

```
struct CameraView: NSViewRepresentable {
class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    // Implement delegate methods if needed
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator()
}

func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
    let view = NSView()

    // Find the FaceTime camera device using AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession
    let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
    if let camera = discoverySession.devices.first(where: { $0.localizedName.contains("FaceTime") }) {
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)

                let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
                previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

                view.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                // Start the capture session
                captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        } catch {
            // Handle the error
            print("Error initializing AVCaptureDeviceInput: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: FaceTime camera not found.")
    }

    return view
}

func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    // Update the view if needed
}
}
```